# Can't get all the necessary links from web-page via Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to use some automation while performing a patent searching task. I'd like to get all the links corresponding to search query result. Particularly, I'm interested in Apple patents starting from the year 2015. So the code is the next one -

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

new_driver_path = r"C:/Users/alexe/Desktop/Apple/PatentSearch/geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64/geckodriver.exe"

ops = options()
serv = Service(new_driver_path)
browser1 = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, options=ops)
browser1.get("https://patents.google.com/?assignee=apple&after=priority:20150101&sort=new")

elements = browser1.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "search-result-item")

links = []
for elem in elements:
    href = elem.get_attribute('href')
    if href:
        links.append(href)

links = set(links)
for href in links:
    print(href)
```

And the output is the next one -

```
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ed/06/50/67e30960a7f68d/JP2021152951A.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/86/30/47/7bc39ddf0e1ea7/KR20210106968A.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ca/2a/bc/9380e1657c2767/US20210318798A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/c1/1a/c6/024f785fd5ea10/AU2021204695A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/b3/19/cc/8dc1fae714194f/US20210312694A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/e6/16/c0/292a198e6f1197/AU2021218193A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/3e/77/e0/b59cf47c2b30a1/AU2021212005A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/1b/3d/c2/ad77a8c9724fbc/AU2021204422A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ad/bc/0f/d1fcc65e53963e/US20210314041A1.pdf
```

The problem here is that I've got 1 missing link -

[result item and the missing link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWGxr.png)

So I've tried different selectors and still got the same result - one link is missing. I've also tried to search with different parameters and the pattern is the next one - all the missing links aren't linked with pdf output. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out what's the reason, so I would be really grateful If you could provide me with any clue on the matter. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The option highlighted has no `a` tag with `class` `pdflink` in it. Put the line of code to extract the link in `try` block. If the required element is not found, search for the `a` tag available for that article.

Try like below once:

```
driver.get("https://patents.google.com/?assignee=apple&after=priority:20150101&sort=new")

articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")

print(len(articles))

for article in articles:
    try:
        link = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'pdfLink')]").get_attribute("href") # Use a dot in the xpath to find an element with in an element.
        print(link)
    except:
        print("Exception")
        link = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//a").get_attribute("href")
        print(link)
```

```
10
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/86/30/47/7bc39ddf0e1ea7/KR20210106968A.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/e6/16/c0/292a198e6f1197/AU2021218193A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/3e/77/e0/b59cf47c2b30a1/AU2021212005A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/c1/1a/c6/024f785fd5ea10/AU2021204695A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/1b/3d/c2/ad77a8c9724fbc/AU2021204422A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ca/2a/bc/9380e1657c2767/US20210318798A1.pdf
Exception
https://patents.google.com/?assignee=apple&after=priority:20150101&sort=new#
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/b3/19/cc/8dc1fae714194f/US20210312694A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ed/06/50/67e30960a7f68d/JP2021152951A.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ad/bc/0f/d1fcc65e53963e/US20210314041A1.pdf
```

Comment: I've checked that once again - you were right! Thanks a lot! By the way - it occured to me that I did get correct script output all the time but I dismissed correct links since I couldn't use them - but these links were completely fine within Google Patent search bar, but they are not meant to be used outside of it - via browser bar. Now it's fine, thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

To extract all the `href` attributes of the *pdfs* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.search-result-item[href]")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'search-result-item') and @href]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/86/30/47/7bc39ddf0e1ea7/KR20210106968A.pdf', 'https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/e6/16/c0/292a198e6f1197/AU2021218193A1.pdf', 'https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/3e/77/e0/b59cf47c2b30a1/AU2021212005A1.pdf', 'https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/c1/1a/c6/024f785fd5ea10/AU2021204695A1.pdf', 'https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/1b/3d/c2/ad77a8c9724fbc/AU2021204422A1.pdf', 'https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ca/2a/bc/9380e1657c2767/US20210318798A1.pdf', 'https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/b3/19/cc/8dc1fae714194f/US20210312694A1.pdf', 'https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ed/06/50/67e30960a7f68d/JP2021152951A.pdf', 'https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ad/bc/0f/d1fcc65e53963e/US20210314041A1.pdf']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> PS: You can extract only nine(9) *href* attributes as one of the search items is a `<span>` element and isn't a link i.e. doesn't have the *href* attribute